# Setting nodeValue of a DOMelement : error :Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, dom

When running this php script :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTMLFile("some_url.html");
    $ele1 = $doc->getElementById ( "coupon" );
    if($ele1->length){
    $doc->getElementById ( "coupon" )->item(0)->nodeValue =$result["affiliate_name"] ;}
```

I get : `Trying to get property of non-object` in the last line
if it's not the right way to do it, how can I set the text of tag that I must extract usig its Id.

here is my some_url.html :

```
  <div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 id="coupon" class="panel-title">Coupon name 1</h3>
    </div>
<p id="coupon_id" hidden>coupon id</p>
    <div id="counter-up" class="panel-body">
      0
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide the contents of `some_url.html` or at least a shortened example of it?

Comment: I added the content of some_url.html

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation, `getElementById()` returns a single `DOMElement`, which extends `DOMNode`, which in turn has the `$nodeValue` field you are trying to change. A `DOMNode` is not a `DOMNodeList`, so it has neither the `$length` field nor the `item()` method. Because of that, you aren't supposed to call `item()` on that element, you can directly manipulate its `$nodeValue`. To find out whether such element exists, simply test the result of `getElementById()` for equality with `NULL` (or use `if ($element)` as a shorthand). Complete code would look as follows:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("some_url.html");
$ele1 = $doc->getElementById("coupon");
if ($ele1) $ele1->nodeValue = $result["affiliate_name"];
```

Sources:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php

Comment: When doing this I get null which means that it does not find the id, is there something wrong with the way I'm doing it

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Your HTML does contain the element with the specified ID, so it should work. Maybe `loadHTMLFile()` fails for some reason (e.g. wrong path)? `loadHTMLFile()` returns `true` on success and `false` on failure, check that to make sure the file is correctly loaded.

Comment: Try checking the loaded HTML either by doing `echo $doc->saveHTML();` and then viewing the source in your browser or printing everything as plain text, like this: `header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'); echo $doc->saveHTML();`. Using the latter way you can see the HTML directly; note that `header()` must be called before you `echo` anything. If it seems that everything is indeed loaded correctly and it still does not work, then please post your current PHP code.